# Django Generic Views: How to assign a new property?

Tags: python, django, class, django-generic-views

I'm new to Python and trying to figure out Django 1.3's class-based generic views. Right now, I have the following view which gets a list of Location objects in a Category:

```
class category_detail(ListView):
    """Return a generic view of locations in a category."""

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context.
        context = super(category_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add the current category to the context.
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        context['category'] = category
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Location.objects.filter(category=category)
```

It does what I want it to do. But you can see that I'm repeating myself by defining `category` twice. Is there a way I can add a new property to the class called `category` that I define once at the top, and then just reference `self.category` in `get_queryset()` and `get_context_data()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should approach it from a different angle: you should not be using `ListView` showing the `Locations` of a `Category` but a `DetailView` of a `Category` that also includes the `Locations` of that category. The name of your view class also suggests that you're showing a detail view of a category. I think it should look more like this:

```
class CategoryLocationsView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryLocationsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['location_list'] = self.get_object().location_set.all()
        return context
```

You now have both the category and the list of locations in your context which you can use in the template.

Comment: +1. Also, you can simplify the code further by dropping the `get_context_data` method entirely, and put `{% with location_list=category.location_set.all %}` in the template.

Comment: This makes much more sense than what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just assign category to `self`. The only caveat is that you need to be a little careful about where you do that, because some methods are called before others. However, `get_queryset` is one of the first things activated on a view, so it'll work fine there:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return Location.objects.filter(category=self.category)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context.
    context = super(category_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add the current category to the context.
    context['category'] = self.category
    return context
```

FWIW, this is actually the exact method used by the [Django docs on class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering) (third code sample down).

Answer (score 1):

use the `@property` decorator

```
@property
def category(self):
    return get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

inside your class and then you can access it as `self.category`, without the decorator it would be accessible with `self.category()`